Is Death actually unaware of these characters?
In the Netflix series Dead Boy Detectives,

 the titular characters spend a lot of time hiding from Death, trying to avoid being taken to the Afterlife. They even resort to hiding outside the window of their office and peeking in when she unexpectedly comes to guide another ghost to the afterlife.

Not only is Death one of the Endless, possessed of great cosmic power, but knowing where dead spirits are is basically her main job. It seems somewhat unlikely that she could be fooled by the old "hiding just outside the window" trick.
Furthermore, she is definitionally present wherever anyone is dying (unless, perhaps, they are dragged off to Hell or manage to fall through the cracks?), meaning that it would kind of hard to avoid accidentally being in the same place as her for decades (something like hundreds of people die in London every day!)
Have these characters actually managed to successfully hide from Death? Or does Death choose to ignore them for whatever reason?

In the comics she seems mildly irritated by their refusal to come with her (at the outset) and then just content to ignore them.

Following on from Valorum's comment above, at the time there was some kind of crisis she had to deal with (maybe a lot of dead escaping from Hell), and she didn't have time to waste trying to persuade them to come with her. I think they also weren't sure how long they could keep ahead of her, and saw every minute of the time they still had as a precious opportunity for some joy and happiness until then.
